# Array.filter() in Typescript when complex object inside

Tags: typescript

As title. For example, I have an array that saves some student's name and test scores....

```
var arrStudents=[{"Name":"John","Math":90,"English":80},
{"Name":"Johnson","Math":85,"English":95},
{"Name":"Mary","Math":70,"English":78},
{"Name":"Maria","Math":83,"English":88},
{"Name":"Peter","Math":86,"English":79},
{"Name":"Marx","Math:79,"English":62}];
```

And, I want to find the records that student's name contains 'Ma'....

```
var arrResult=arrStudents.filter(x=>x["Name"].contains("Ma"));
```

In normal Javascript that is OK, but I got error about x in TypeScript because I want to use it in my Angular project.  I've searched but most pages that introduces the usage of array.filter use arrays of simple data types (numbers, strings).  Could someone guide me to achieve this?

Comment: What was the error? What was the exact code you used?

Comment: The error might be because you use `String.contains()` - that is not a string function. Try `String.includes()`.

Comment: Because I'm a Taiwanese, I can only translate the error I met: "parameter 'x' implicitly has an 'any' type"

Answer (score 1):

There is no `contains` method in the prototype of Array-String in Js instead use `includes`

[MDN includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```
var arrStudents = [{ "Name": "John", "Math": 90, "English": 80 },
{ "Name": "Johnson", "Math": 85, "English": 95 },
{ "Name": "Mary", "Math": 70, "English": 78 },
{ "Name": "Maria", "Math": 83, "English": 88 },
{ "Name": "Peter", "Math": 86, "English": 79 },
{ "Name": "Marx", "Math": 79, "English": 62 }];

// var arrResult = arrStudents.filter(x => x["Name"].contains("Ma"));

var arrResult2 = arrStudents.filter(x => x["Name"].includes("Ma"));

console.log(arrResult2);
```